# css3 display: grid; or grid-column-start: isn't working

Tags: html, css, grid

I want to use the new grid module in CSS but it isn't working.

This is the code I have:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
}

p {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Hello World! :D
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working properly, you just need to visualise it better. Try adding some other child elements to your main container, you'd see `Hello world` is positioned where it should be. It is just because you have empty space all around, you are having difficulty

```css
div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  background: green;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

p {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <p>
    Hello World! :D
  </p>
</div>
```